# Unable to install nodeclipse plugin on Eclipse Mars

Tags: node.js, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, nodeclipse

How do I resolve "Unable to read repository at http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/1" error? I'm giving the url - http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/1
Also tried without '1' in the url

Both don't seem to work. What could be the problem?

[image: [enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF2SZ.jpg)

Comment: It may be temporary, but the http://www.nodeclipse.org/ website seems to be offline. You could try the marketplace: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nodeclipse

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look [here](http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/) first.

As Jonah Graham mentioned, go to [marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nodeclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nodeclipse). Once there, click the *External Install Button* tab. Bottom-right is *Output* **Install**.  Drag **Install** to your running Eclipse.  Then follow the prompts.

Comment: For Mac OS/X specific help you can look [here](http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-install-nodeclipse-on-mac-osx.html)